# How To reference a column from within a created Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In  this code I want to use My materials date (A column created from the query) as an indicator of whether or not the number 2 appears in the 2 column. Pseudo-code for what I would want in the 2nd column would be:
  "If [Materials] is Null THEN '2'" This is what is attemped in my last Case Statement. I aplogize if I posted incorrectly, this is one of my first SQL assignments/posts on this website.

```
USE [MARKData]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


SELECT DISTINCT
 ord.[OrderID] AS 'Quote #',
 Null As 'T',
 con.[FirstName] +  ' ' + con.[LastName] AS 'Customer Name',
 stat.[StatusDescription] AS 'Current Status',
  '$' + CONVERT(varchar(12), ord.[OrderTotal], 1) AS 'Current Total',
 stath.[UpdateDate] AS 'Last Status Update',
 (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), ord.[OrderSubmitDate]) * -1) AS 'Current Elapsed Days',

CASE 
 WHEN stath.[OrderStatusID] = 35
 THEN stath.[CreateDate]
ELSE
 CASE
  WHEN stath.[CreateDate] >= MatPriceRev.[CreateDate]
  THEN MatPriceRev.[CreateDate]
  ELSE NULL  
 END
END AS 'Materials',

CASE 
 WHEN stath.[OrderStatusID] = 34
 THEN stath.[CreateDate]
ELSE
 CASE
  WHEN stath.[CreateDate] >= EngineerRev.[CreateDate]
  THEN EngineerRev.[CreateDate]
  ELSE NULL  
 END
END AS 'Engineer Notified',

 ConSales.[FirstName] +  ' ' + ConSales.[LastName] AS 'Sales Rep', 

CASE
 WHEN ord.[CreateDate] < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
 THEN '1'
END AS '1',

CASE
 WHEN 'Materials' IS NULL
 THEN '2'
END AS '2'


FROM T_Order ord
 LEFT JOIN T_Contact con ON ord.[ContactID] = con.[ContactID]
 LEFT JOIN T_Contact ConSales ON ord.CreateUser = ConSales.[ContactID]
 LEFT JOIN T_OrderStatusHistory stath ON ord.[OrderID] = stath.[OrderID]
 LEFT JOIN T_OrderStatus stat ON stath.[OrderStatusID] = stat.[OrderStatusID]
 LEFT JOIN 
 (Select * From T_OrderStatusHistory Where T_OrderStatusHistory.[OrderStatusID] = 35) AS MatPriceRev 
  ON MatPriceRev.[OrderID] = ord.[OrderID]
 LEFT JOIN 
 (Select * From T_OrderStatusHistory Where T_OrderStatusHistory.[OrderStatusID] = 34) AS EngineerRev 
  ON EngineerRev.[OrderID] = ord.[OrderID]
 LEFT JOIN
 (Select * From T_OrderStatusHistory Where T_OrderStatusHistory.[OrderStatusID] = 41) AS RiskRev 
  ON RiskRev.[OrderID] = ord.[OrderID]



WHERE
 DATEDIFF(DAY, ord.OrderSubmitDate, GETDATE()) >= 0
 AND stath.[CurrentIndicator] = 'True' 
 AND stath.[OrderStatusID] <> 2

ORDER BY 'Quote #' ASC, 'Last Status Update' ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
CASE WHEN 
    CASE WHEN stath.[OrderStatusID] = 35
        THEN stath.[CreateDate]
    WHEN stath.[CreateDate] >= MatPriceRev.[CreateDate]
        THEN MatPriceRev.[CreateDate]
    ELSE NULL  
    END  
 IS NULL THEN '2' END AS '2'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't allow you to use a computed column in the same query. One way to work around it is to wrap you query in a CTE, which then allows you to refer to the computed column in subsequent query:

```
;WITH tmp AS (
SELECT DISTINCT
 ord.[OrderID] AS 'Quote #',
 Null As 'T',
 con.[FirstName] +  ' ' + con.[LastName] AS 'Customer Name',
 stat.[StatusDescription] AS 'Current Status',
  '$' + CONVERT(varchar(12), ord.[OrderTotal], 1) AS 'Current Total',
 stath.[UpdateDate] AS 'Last Status Update',
 (DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), ord.[OrderSubmitDate]) * -1) AS 'Current Elapsed Days',

CASE 
 WHEN stath.[OrderStatusID] = 35
 THEN stath.[CreateDate]
ELSE
 CASE
  WHEN stath.[CreateDate] >= MatPriceRev.[CreateDate]
  THEN MatPriceRev.[CreateDate]
  ELSE NULL  
 END
END AS 'Materials',

CASE 
 WHEN stath.[OrderStatusID] = 34
 THEN stath.[CreateDate]
ELSE
 CASE
  WHEN stath.[CreateDate] >= EngineerRev.[CreateDate]
  THEN EngineerRev.[CreateDate]
  ELSE NULL  
 END
END AS 'Engineer Notified',

 ConSales.[FirstName] +  ' ' + ConSales.[LastName] AS 'Sales Rep', 

CASE
 WHEN ord.[CreateDate] < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
 THEN '1'
END AS '1',

FROM T_Order ord
 LEFT JOIN T_Contact con ON ord.[ContactID] = con.[ContactID]
 LEFT JOIN T_Contact ConSales ON ord.CreateUser = ConSales.[ContactID]
 LEFT JOIN T_OrderStatusHistory stath ON ord.[OrderID] = stath.[OrderID]
 LEFT JOIN T_OrderStatus stat ON stath.[OrderStatusID] = stat.[OrderStatusID]
 LEFT JOIN 
 (Select * From T_OrderStatusHistory Where T_OrderStatusHistory.[OrderStatusID] = 35) AS MatPriceRev 
  ON MatPriceRev.[OrderID] = ord.[OrderID]
 LEFT JOIN 
 (Select * From T_OrderStatusHistory Where T_OrderStatusHistory.[OrderStatusID] = 34) AS EngineerRev 
  ON EngineerRev.[OrderID] = ord.[OrderID]
 LEFT JOIN
 (Select * From T_OrderStatusHistory Where T_OrderStatusHistory.[OrderStatusID] = 41) AS RiskRev 
  ON RiskRev.[OrderID] = ord.[OrderID]



WHERE
 DATEDIFF(DAY, ord.OrderSubmitDate, GETDATE()) >= 0
 AND stath.[CurrentIndicator] = 'True' 
 AND stath.[OrderStatusID] <> 2
)

SELECT    *,
          CASE WHEN Materials IS NULL THEN 2 END AS [2]
FROM      tmp
ORDER BY  [Quote #], [Last Status Update]
```